# Converting a specific JSON to java object format?

Tags: java, javascript, json

Iam new to java script and JSON, please help me in solving my problem. Below is the structure of my JSON in JavaScript

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "def": [
        {
            "setId": 1,
            "setDef": [
                {
                    "name": "ABC",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "XYZ",
                    "type": "STRING"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "setId": 2,
            "setDef": [
                {
                    "name": "abc",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "xyz",
                    "type": "STRING"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

in the backend, what should be the synatx of java method to receive this data

```
public void getJsonData(****){

}
```

How to parse this JSON data in java and what should be the syntax of method parameter ?

update 1: Edited the json format to make it valid

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look on Java string parsing or the numerous JSON parsers around.

Comment: The JSON syntax is invalid: `setDef:{
                    ["name":'ABC', "type":'STRING'],["name":XYZ,type:"STRING"]
                    }`

Comment: This is not valid JSON...

Comment: @KevinBowersox not to mention the missing commas, the unquoted object member names, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a class that will map your json object and give a name something like "DataObject". Then use the gson library and do the following:

```
String s = "";
DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(s, DataObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, but assuming you fix that then you are looking for a library in Java which will serialize an annotated Java class to JSON, or deserialize JSON data to an annotated Java class.

There is a whole list of suitable libraries here:

http://json.org/java/